# Logback db appender mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, logback

As per Logback documentation, i have the following configuration file

```
    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
        <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <jdbcUrl>${jdbc.url}</jdbcUrl>
            <user>${jdbc.username}</user>
            <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
        </dataSource>
    </connectionSource>
    <sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <insertHeaders>true</insertHeaders>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Error

```
    Jun 11, 2013 6:55:59 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Jun 11, 2013 6:55:59 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
Jun 11, 2013 6:55:59 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hgeby98vdjuesl1wggnsn|891d76, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgeby98vdjuesl1wggnsn|891d76, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc.url_IS_UNDEFINED, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
Jun 11, 2013 6:56:28 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@5d5033 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:223)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Jun 11, 2013 6:56:28 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1300800 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Add mysql driver i,e "mysql-connector-java-verison-bin.jar" into your classpath.
You can download it from here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/